# Can't use rsDriver function in R

Tags: r, rselenium, netstat

I can't run the rsDriver function in the RSelenium package

when I run this:

```r
rd <- rsDriver(browser = 'chrome', chromever = '114.0.5735.16', verbose = FALSE, port= free_port(), iedrver = NULL)
```

I get the following error:

> Could not open chrome browser. Client error message: Undefined error
> in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 14415
> after 0 ms: Connection refused Check server log for further details.
> Warning message: In rsDriver(browser = "chrome", chromever =
> "114.0.5735.16", verbose = FALSE,  :   Could not determine server
> status.